# Finding coefficient of $x_n$ term in exponential generating functions

Tags: combinatorics, recurrence-relations, taylor-expansion, generating-functions

I'm working on some problems that involve generating functions, and I've been able to understand when exponential vs. ordinary generating functions are used and how to write a generating function to solve a given problem. Where I get stuck is finding the coefficient of $x_n$ for exponential generating functions. Here is an example of what I have tried, but I don't know where to go from there. Any advice would be appreciated.

$$G(x) = (1 + \frac{x^2}{2!} + \frac{x^4}{4!} + ...) (1 + x + \frac{x^2}{2!} +\frac{x^3}{3!} + ...) (1 + x + \frac{x^2}{2!} + \frac{x^3}{3!} + ...) (1+x) $$ 
$$= \frac{e^x + e^{-x}}{2} e^x e^x (1+x)$$ $$= \frac{1}{2} (e^{3x} +e^x)(1+x) $$
$$= \frac{1}{2} (\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} 3^n \frac{x^n}{n!} + \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{x^n}{n!}) (1+x) = \frac{1}{2} (\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} (3^n + 1) \frac{x^n}{n!}) (1+x)$$

Comment: $$\ldots=\frac 12\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{3^n+1}{n!}(x^n+x^{n+1})=\frac 12\left(\frac{3^0+1}{0!}+\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{3^n+1}{n!}x^n+\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{3^n+1}{n!}x^{n+1}\right)=\frac 12\left(\frac{3^0+1}{0!}+\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{3^n+1}{n!}x^n+\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{3^{n-1}+1}{(n-1)!}x^n\right)=\ldots~\\~$$
Can you proceed from here?

Answer (score 1):

In this example, the coefficient of $x^n$ is
$$\frac12\left(\frac{3^n+1}{n!}+\frac{3^{n-1}+1}{(n-1)!}\right).$$

Comment: Notice that for $n=0$, the expression becomes undefined. You need to add that this is valid only for $n\geq 1$ and the coefficient of $x^0$, i.e., the constant term is given by $\frac 12\times\frac{3^0+1}{0!}=1$

Answer (score 1):

You're very close. Let $a_{-1}=0$. Then:

$$(1+x)\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_nx^n=\sum_{n=0}a_nx^n+\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_{n-1} x^{n}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty (a_n+a_{n-1})x^n$$